# RestAPI and domain design - best practices

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, restful-url

I have some general question about best practices for the design of domain and rest API.
Let's say that we have some domain object - customer, which is described for such attributes: id, name, surname, products.

Currently, we don't care about the date, and provide information for current status via such URL: `/api/v1/customers/{id}`

Now, there is a requirement to provide information about customers for any requested date, so I'm wondering, what is the best way to create URL:
1. should it be by `@PathVariable`: `/api/v1/customers/{id}/{date}`
2. or by `@RequestParam`: `/api/v1/customers/{id}?date=XXX`

The other question is, should I also change my domain object and add some additional field like start_dt/end_dt/both of them or any of them (I can just change my DB table, and query historical table, so it' ll required only changes in DB layer, but not in my main service).

what are the best solutions for that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "information about customers for any requested date". How the `Customer` will differ? Do you want only to return the `date` of the `Customer` or the historical information about him at the certain date? I don't understand how the output would differ.

Comment: Date format will be the same, but data content can change.
E.g Let's say that today our customer has 2 products, so when we GET `/api/v1/customers/1` the response is `{"id": "1", "name": "John", "surname": "TestSurname", "products": ["prod1", "prod2"]}` In the next week, he make some changes in his products, so when we GET `/api/v1/customers/1` the response is `{"id": "1", "name": "John", "surname": "TestSurname", "products": ["prod2", "prod5"]}`.

Comment: But we can also make GET for customer information for any date in the past. E.g
 But we can also make GET '/api/v1/customers/1?date=2020-05-20' the response should be '{"id": "1", "name": "John", "surname": "TestSurname", "products": ["prod1", "prod2"]}'. It is state of customer for given date.
My question is what are best practices for URL: it should be: '/api/v1/customers/1?date=2020-05-20' or '/api/v1/customers/1/2020-05-20'

Answer (score 0):

You should use option II, the query parameter (or `@RequestParam`). This is the better choice because it maintains **backward compatibility** with the current way that customers are queried. You specified...

> Currently, we don't care about date

Using a query parameter keeps the same endpoint compatible with old-style requests while extending its function to allow date-specific queries.

Regarding a start date and end date, the answer depends on what you're trying to deliver. In *most cases*, a date-range is more useful than a single date, and so the start/end system is preferable. I will proceed assuming that this is the case for you.

The most elegant way to do all this would be to utilize the [`defaultValue`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#defaultValue--) attribute of the `@RequestParam`s. You can set the default `start_dt` to the beginning of time (typically [January 1, 1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) and the default `end_dt` to the end of time (either [January 19, 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) or January 31, 9999 or positive infinity). By doing this, your API will function exactly the same as before if the user doesn't specify either query parameter (it will return results for all time). But the user can restrict the time range of their according to their needs.

Comment: We don't have to worry about backward compatibility, it can be released as `/api/v2`, and the information will be available at new endpoint.
Is query parameter used for filtering of the results? In my case, it isn't filtering of results, but just setting the requested value (instead of the default one, which is current date)

Comment: Is this going to be a GET request?